# Faster way to find items from one list in another one

Tags: c#, performance, collections

I would like to check if a string appears in a list of strings. For that, I have chosen the `List<string>` type, as follows:

```
public List<string> list_statuses;

// list_statuses gets filled with 173 entries

// Regular execution of:
string text_list = ...; // Mostly, this is an empty string
int list_statuses_count = list_statuses == null? 0 : list_statuses.Count;
int text_list_count = text_list == null? 0 : text_list.Count();

log.Debug($"Before the foreach: list_statuses contains [{list_statuses_count}] elements, " + 
          "and textList contains [{text_list_count}] elements");
foreach (string entry2 in list_statuses)
{
    if ((text_list == null) ||
        (!text_list.Contains(entry2)))
    {
        // do_something();
    }
}
log.Debug("After the foreach");
```

Examples of log entries:

```
2022-03-21 17:06:58.6534 | Debug | Before the foreach: list_statuses contains [173] elements, 
                                   and textList contains [0] elements 
2022-03-21 17:07:00.5896 | Debug | After the foreach
```

=> duration : ±2 seconds

```
2022-03-21 17:07:00.6455 | Debug | Before the foreach: list_statuses contains [173] elements, 
                                   and textList contains [0] elements 
2022-03-21 17:07:02.3970 | Debug | After the foreach
```

=> duration: ±2 seconds

```
2022-03-21 17:07:02.4416 | Debug | Before the foreach: list_statuses contains [173] elements, 
                                   and textList contains [0] elements 
2022-03-21 17:07:04.1687 | Debug | After the foreach
```

=> duration: ±2 seconds

This piece of code is needed inside a server application. Waiting about 2 seconds for a simple search is quite long. Is there another way to run through a list of strings in another way? (Both the "list of strings" type and the "way to run" (foreach) may be replaced)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134964/discussion-on-question-by-dominique-faster-way-to-find-items-from-one-list-in-an).

Comment: The code contains `// do_something();` that makes the question off-topic on code review because it is missing code review context. For performance issues we need to be able to see more of the code to help you find the bottleneck.

Comment: @pacmaninbw: this is too harsh: the whole idea is to emphasise that the performance is certainly not inside that piece of code, as indicated clearly in the question.

Comment: This is not stack overflow. We require more code.

Comment: Which part of those 2 seconds is used by logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to boost the performance is to take advantage of sorting.

So if you can sort the `list_statuses` and you can sort the split version of the `text_list` then the lookup could be faster

```
IEnumerable<string> words = text_list.Split(" ").Distinct().OrderBy(w => w); 
IEnumerable<string> statuses = list_statuses.OrderBy(s => s);
```

Note: I've added a `Distinct` call as well to make sure that all unique words a present only once.

Finding all matches:

```
var matches = words.Intersect(statuses);
```

Finding the first match:

```
var firstMatch = words.FirstOrDefault(statuses.Contains);
```

---

If you want to reuse the ordered `list_statuses` multiple times then it would make sense to store the materialized version of it .

Comment: Would it be better to have words as a `HashSet<string>` and use `IntersectsWith(statuses)`? That will also ensure uniqueness by definition.

Comment: @RobH Well in that case I'm not sure that we can take advantage of the sorting. But it would worth to give it a try.

Comment: @RobH Maybe with a `SortedSet<string>` we can take advantage of both uniqueness and alphabetic ordering.

Comment: This question really should not have been answered.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Are you suggesting to delete my answer?

Comment: No, just saying in the future if the question is missing as much context as this one is don't answer it. The questions currently has 3 votes to close.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I did not want to post an answer. As you can see I've posted this code as a comment first. Then the OP said that solution worked for him and he wanted to reward the effort...

Comment: @pacmaninbw: what's the problem with my question? I had a performance problem, so I decided not to post it on Stackoverflow, but here. I have answered all questions, asked in comments and as a result an answer has been given which has increased the speed of my application times 100! Hence my immediate upvote and acceptance of the answer. What's wrong with this?